# How to Create BottomBar in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity created `Tablayout` using `Viewpager` adapter , I took 4 `Fragments` like
Home_Fragment,
News_Fragment,
Video_Fragment,
PodCast_Fragment,
More_Fragment,
tablayout working fine...
but how to create Bottombar only in Home_Fragment?

I follow this link : https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar
am getting bottombar for all fragments

I want bottombar only in home_fragment???

am trying a lot but not getting.

[image]

Comment: hide that battombar in other Fragments

Comment: how to hide bottombar in other fragments???

Comment: any one help me about bottombar??/

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, remove onCreateOptionsMenu in your MainActivity and create onCreateOptionsMenu() to your HomeFragment like,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

// TODO Add your menu entries here
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.YOUR_ITEM_1:
    // do stuff here
    break;

case R.id.YOUR_ITEM_2:
     // do stuff here
    break;
}
return true;

}
```

and then put following code,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

to your HomeFragment.java

this might helps you

Comment: where i put this code whether MainActivity or Home_Fragment?

Comment: then hide menu item

Comment: can i take getVisibleFragment() method??

Comment: when i put above code in MainActivity...getVisibleFrament(); appear in red Colour.. and error is = Error:(121, 32) error: cannot find symbol method getVisibleFragment()

Comment: put my EDIT 3 into MainActivity

Comment: once see that above image

Comment: finally i was modify above edit 3 code....no errors are there...but didnot get output

Comment: when i swipe Home_Fragment to other Fragment, Bottombar was didnt hide....its appear evertime every fragment

Comment: you hide all menu items except HomeFragment

Comment: I took & modify edit 3 code in MainActivity , No errors are occure....but bottombar visible in all fragments ....what should i do??

Comment: show your MainActivity.java code  and menu.xml code

Comment: yes...i can hide bottombar in all fragments except Home_Fragment

Comment: ok...how to post xml code and mainAcitivity code in this site? plz dont irritate me....i started android Project bcz this helpfull me a lot for my life

Comment: i dont need full code. only onCreateOptionsMenu code

Comment: iam also pass menu_items but didnot get

Comment: did you remove onCreateOptionsMenu() @ MainActivity

Comment: hi frnd...i got an idea....in tablayout setOnclickListener method is there.....in this method inside put bottombar.hide(); method...so then its hide for all fragments

Comment: just i want hide all fragments except Home_fragment then what should i do? give me reply???

Comment: create menu only HomeFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
<group android:id="@+id/group_items">
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_us"
    android:icon="@drawable/about"
    android:title="About Us" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/contact_us"
    android:icon="@drawable/contacts"
    android:title="Contact Us" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/donate_us"
    android:icon="@drawable/donate"
    android:title="Donate Us" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not tried attach BottomBar to View?

`BottomBar` contains `public static BottomBar Attach(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` that provide functionality that you needed.

So, in you `home_fragment` insert code in OnCreate method:

```
_bottomBar = BottomBar.Attach(containerView, savedInstanceState);
```

or in Java

```
bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(containerView, savedInstanceState);
```